# Non-breaking space with Django template code and Bootstrap 4 badges

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to keep text generated with Django template language which is contained within a Bootstrap 4 badge together with some additional text that is not contained in the badge.

Here is my code:

```
<span>Submitted&nbsp;by:&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-primary">{{ 
user.username }}</span></span>
```

I want all the words in the phrase "Submitted by USER" to always be on the same line, but the code above does not achieve that. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the class `text-nowrap` to the outer `<span>` element and remove the unnecessary `&nbsp;`.

`text-nowrap` in Bootstrap 4 prevents wrapping as the name suggests.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 bg-success">
            <span class="text-nowrap">Submitted by: <span class="badge badge-primary">Usernameverylongusernameevenlongerthanthat</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. Just added it. Thanks!